# sql statement to join three tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I need help

I have three tables as below :

```
customers [ CID , name , address , phone ] 

contracts [ ID , CID , TotalPrice , ] 

Payment [ ID , CID , pay ]
```

I want to get the name of customer , his phone number and 
the value of sum( contracts .TotalPrice ) - sum(Payment.pay) as Remaning

but i have trouble to do this

I use microsoft access 2007

I use this statment

```
select customers.name , customers.phone , customers.address, (sum( contracts .TotalPrice ) - sum(Payment.pay)) as Remaning from customers  inner join  contracts on customers.CID=contracts.CID  inner join Payment on contracts.CID=Payment.CID ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select customers.CID ,customers.[name] , customers.phone , customers.address, 
(sum( contracts .TotalPrice ) - sum(Payment.pay)) as Remaning 
from customers  inner join  contracts on customers.CID=contracts.CID  
inner join Payment on contracts.CID=Payment.CID GROUP BY customers.CID";
```

Edit: You need to enclose reserved keywords with '[]' in MS Access

Comment: Note that name is a reserved word in Ms Access